# Python paramiko SSH: why doesn't reading of stdout free some buffer space?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, openssh

I'm writing testing code to check how does the SSH buffer work, and how exactly many bytes of none-read output blocks the remote program from proceeding. Here is the code:

Client side:

```
from paramiko import SSHClient, AutoAddPolicy
from datetime import datetime


def log(msg, *args, **kwargs):
    dt_str = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    print(f"[{dt_str}] {msg}", *args, **kwargs)


def main():
    ssh_client = SSHClient()
    ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh_client.connect(hostname='127.0.0.1', username='my_user', password='my_password', port=3322)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command('python3 /home/my_user/long_output.py', timeout=30)

    log('Print stdout')
    for line in stdout:
        log(line, end='')

    log('Print stderr')
    for line in stderr:
        print(line, end='')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The client side code works fine with scripts which generate ordinary size of output. But I want to test how exactly many of bytes of output blocks the program, so I made the following server side script (save it on the SSH server under $HOME with name as 'long_output.py'):

```
import sys
import string
from time import sleep


def main():
    print('started', flush=True)  # [a] 8 bytes to <stdout>
    sleep(2)
    s = string.ascii_letters+string.digits+string.punctuation + '\n'  # length of each line: 95 bytes
    # target size: 2 MiB = 2 * 1024 * 1024 = 2097152 bytes
    for _ in range(22075):
        # 22075 * 95 = 2097125 bytes of content is written to <stderr>
        print(s, end='', file=sys.stderr)
    # there are still 2097152 - 2097125 = 27 bytes to the target size
    print('123456789' + '\n', end='', file=sys.stderr)  # [b] but actually you can add at most 9 bytes only
    sleep(2)
    print('finished', flush=True)  # [c] 9 bytes to <stdout>


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My client side code reads **stdout** first, so if there is too much **stderr** which fills up the buffer , the client side code won't get a chance to read any more data from **stdout**. Size of the buffer is 2 MiB, i.e. 2,097,152 bytes, but I found that my client side code hangs when server side **stderr** is more than 2,097,134 bytes, which is 18 bytes less than the limitation. You can try it by modifying line [b] in server side code: if charater '9' is removed, the client side works fine, otherwise it blocks.

I thought those 18 bytes are used by some overhead data, such as controlling flags. But soon I found that by removing some characters from line [a] and [c], the client code works again. So I think the buffer is shared by **stdout** and **stderr**, and the limitation is exactly 2 MiB - 1 byte.

But it brings me a new question: I've read the **stdout** in the client side code! Why doesn't the 8 bytes + 9 bytes of **stdout** get freed from the buffer?

As per documentation of paramiko:

> Because SSH2 has a windowing kind of flow control, if you stop reading
> data from a Channel and its buffer fills up, the server will be unable
> to send you any more data until you read some of it.

(https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel)

I have "read some of it" (the **stdout**), why can't the server side script write more **stderr** data to the buffer?

Platform information:

- Client side: Windows 10, Python 3.8.10, paramiko 3.1.0
- Server side: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, Python 3.8.10, OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020

Comment: Perhaps you're not reading as much as or more than the window size?